# How to stop stunnel in linux server(using terminal only), other than killing pid

Tags: stunnel

We have configures our stunnel properly in Ubuntu 16.04 , also it is starting properly we are getting our data in application which comes from stunnel server. Although I cannot find any proper way to stop stunnel. I tried killing the pid of stunnel , but killing pid is not a proper way to stop.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Killing the PID sounds pretty bad, but it is the common way to stop processes in linux. "Kill" is just another name for "send signal". If you issue a `kill $pid`, then a SIGTERM is sent to that process.
The process can then handle the signal and perform a clean shutdown. This is also the way many programs implement a configuration reloading functionality, they often use SIGHUP for that (`kill -SIGHUP $pid`).

So, as long as you don't use `kill -SIGKILL $pid` (or in short: `kill -9 $pid`) the program can handle that signal and gracefully shutdown.

More about signals on linux: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#List_of_signals

Answer (score 2):

There are could be several of `stunnel` processes:

```
[root@someserver ~]# ps aux | grep stunnel | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
13527
13528
13529
13530
13531
13532
```

The following bash-one-line loop could handle to kill them all:

```
if kill $(ps aux | grep stunnel | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'); then echo "Done"; else echo "No ps left"; fi
```